# Javascript validation does not work for g:form validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am attempting to validate all form elements using a javascript function which is as follows:

```
function validateForm() {
                    //var inpObj = document.getElementById("myForm").elements;
                    var inpObj = document.getElementById("myForm");
                    for (var i = 0; i < inpObj.length; i++) {
                        if (inpObj.checkValidity() == false) {
                            document.getElementById("validationErrors").innerHTML = inpObj.validationMessage;
                        } else {
                            document.getElementById("validationErrors").innerHTML = "Input Ok";
                        }
                    }
                }
```

This should validate all elements within myForm and display their error messages if they do not pass validation. However it is not displaying any errors in the validation.even though elements are being left blank on purpose.

The form tag is as follows: `<g:form name="myForm" action="confirmApplyFormSaveToGroup" novalidate="novalidate">` with the action being the redirect if the validation passes.

The function is called when the form is submitted as follows:

```
<div class="ui-block-b"><button type="submit" data-theme="d" onclick="validateForm()">Submit</button></div>
```

The errors are supposed to display in the following paragraph:

```
<p id="validationErrors"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var inpObj = document.getElementById("myForm");
<g:form name="myForm" action="confirmApplyFormSaveToGroup" novalidate="novalidate">
```

You are using `getElementById` but dont have ID on your form.